# How to modify the target folder for generated pact files while doing Contract Driven Testing using ScalaPact

Tags: automated-tests, scalatest, pact

I am using scalapact for CDC test.
My tests are running fine and the pact file is generated under target>pacts folder.

I have another folder "files" where I want those pact files to be generated after running the pact tests.

Is there any way I configure the default path for pact files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an area that needs some attention in Scala-Pact, however, someone kindly did a PR for us a while ago that lets you set an environment variable called `pact.rootDir`.

In practice, on linux/mac that variable is a bit tricky to set because of the `.`, so exporting it or just using `-Dpact.rootDir="<my desired path>"` in the command arguments doesn't seem to work. Instead, you need to do this:
`env "pact.rootDir=<my desired path>" bash`. I haven't tried this on Windows so I don't know if you'd have the same issue.

I've just raised an issue to try and make this easier in the future:
https://github.com/ITV/scala-pact/issues/101

As an alternative, note that the pact directory is really kind of a scratch/tmp area to allow Scala-Pact to compile it's output. If you're running this as part of a build script, you may just want to add a step to copy the assets to a new location once they've been generated.

Also, for some reason we made reading *from* a directory way easier than writing *to* one. If you need to read from a dir such as during verification, you can just add `--source <my desired path>` on the command line.

Hope that helps.